# How to make accessible folder/file to other user

Tags: permissions, filesystems, security

How is it possible to make a folder under $HOME accessible to other users? I thought that's the case why we have softlinks but apparently I am missing some bits  here. Can someone please shed a light on that?

Details:
User Hadoop runs hadoop installaion and that contain bin folder with awailable commands to execute.

```
[hadoop@A1n1 hadoop-1.0.4]$ ls -al
total 7648
drwxr-xr-x. 14 hadoop hadoop    4096 Apr 22  2013 .
drwx------. 11 hadoop hadoop    4096 Oct 30 13:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hadoop hadoop    4096 Feb 27  2013 bin

[hadoop@A1n1 bin]$ ls -al
total 152
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hadoop hadoop  4096 Feb 27  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 hadoop hadoop  4096 Apr 22  2013 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 hadoop hadoop 14137 Oct  3  2012 hadoop
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 hadoop hadoop  2642 Oct  3  2012 hadoop-config.sh
```

I created a softlink pointing to bin folder:

```
[root@A1n1 /usr/local]# ls -l
total 44
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root        4096 Sep 23  2011 bin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   root          29 Nov  1 08:16 hadoop.bin -> /home/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/bin
```

However when I switch to a different user and try to execute a command I get permission denied:

```
[bdst@A1n1 local]$ cd /usr/local/hadoop.bin
bash: cd: /usr/local/hadoop.bin: Permission denied
```

I am not sure what I am missing here as to me it seems that file permissions should be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A symbolic link does not circumvent permissions of the original directory/file. As with direct access you need execute (x) permission on all directories in the path of the original and on the original directory itself. The x is missing on /home/hadoop for others.

Comment: Is there any standard way how to bypass that except making home dir 755 or so?

Comment: You could use 751. That way other users can't see which files are in the home dir, but if they guess a name correctly, they can access it (so this would only be security by obscurity). The real solution would be to place the original directory in a public dir and use a symbolic link inside the home dir.

Comment: Ditto doing it the other way around (put the bin somewhere publicly accessible and symlink it into `/home/hadoop`).

Comment: 755 or 751 I was aware of and undersand that. I just wasn't sure that there wasn't other options (like symlinks - I misunderstood the permissions policy)

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of windows permissions, where everybody typically has the "bypass traverse checking" right, which skips permissions checks in parent folders.

Aside from setting 755/751 or placing the files in a public directory, you could also put your user bdst in the hadoop group, and set the hadoop home directory to 750 or 710.

Answer (score -1):

```
drwx------. 11 hadoop hadoop    4096 Oct 30 13:51 ..
```

I suppose this is your $HOME. Then this is the cause. Anyway, learn about unix permissions and ACL, it would help you.

Comment: Downvoted because this didn't really explain anything.